# Formula for the max number of paths through a grid?

Tags: grid, graph, puzzle

Given a grid of open spots, and a certain number of tiles to place in those spots, what function `f(openSpots, tilesToPlace)` will give you the number of continuous paths you can form?

Continuous paths are placements of the tiles such that each tile shares an edge with another. (Only corners touching is not good enough. So `(0, 1)` and `(0, 0)` are legal, but `(1, 1)` and `(2, 2)` is not.)

I already have a function that will find all these paths. However, it only works for small numbers. For larger values, all I need is a count of how many could possibly exist. Here is some data:

```
For 1 tiles, there are 1 paths.
For 2 tiles, there are 4 paths.
For 3 tiles, there are 22 paths.
For 4 tiles, there are 89 paths.
For 5 tiles, there are 390 paths.
For 6 tiles, there are 1476 paths.
For 7 tiles, there are 5616 paths.
For 8 tiles, there are 19734 paths.
For 9 tiles, there are 69555 paths.
```

This gets really slow to calculate as the puzzle size increases. I think the asymptotic complexity of my path finding solution is pretty bad.

If there are `n` tiles, the grid is at most `n` spots long and wide.

Comment: Should we assume that the initial grid is infinitely large (or at least sufficiently large that the edges can be ignored)?

Comment: Are you sure there are 22 paths for 3 tiles? I can only think of 18.

Comment: @Mark: clarified
and no, I'm not sure it's 22.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's 18. I've written a naive program to calculate it by checking all possibilities recursively, and it also gets 18. I can give you the list of paths I found if you like (tile coordinates for each path). It's also pretty slow for n=9, taking about 30 seconds. Would you like the source code? I suspect that to get faster you would need to use a more intelligent algorithm, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: yeah I'd like to see what you came up with.

Comment: Could you please tell us the paths for n = 2, so we get an idea of how exactly a path is defined?

Comment: A path must start on (0,0). Then you can place the next tile on any of the adjacent squares (-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), or (0,1) giving four paths. Then the next tile must be adjacent to one of the first 2 tiles giving 18 possibilities, etc... I agree that the question should be updated to explain this more clearly.

Comment: @Rosarch: I posted my solution as an answer since it's too big for a comment. It's not an optimal solution, but I think it's a working solution. It think any answer which counts the paths individually will be O(n!) because that seems to be how many paths there are. So to beat that you'd have to reason about how many paths there must be instead of iterating over them one by one. I don't know how though.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I don't think that's what he means, because he said: "If there are n tiles, the grid is at most n spots long and wide.". Your solution for n=2, uses a grid with 5 spots ((0,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0, -1)).

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess a path can start anywhere inside the grid.

Comment: I don't understand how n=3 gives 18 or 22 solutions. n=2 can be thought of a single solution, rotated 90 degrees around the axis 4 times. As such, n=3 would be a single solution, also rotated 90 degrees 4 times. With the first at (0,0) and the second at (1,0), the third would be either (-1,0), (2,0), (0,-1), (0,1), (1,-1), or (1,1), which means 6 ways to place the third tile around the initial 2, then you rotate that 4 times, and you get 24. Please tell me what I'm not getting here. I can't see any of them overlapping to produce duplicate combinations either... Or, hmmm, I think I see it now.

Comment: After changing my program to allow starting from anywhere, I get 1,4,22,113.... so something is still not right. Is there another rule I'm missing?

Comment: Could someone please post the way n=3 gives 22 solutions and possibly what they are?

Comment: Is there a rule something like that the paths must start and end at the edges of the grid?

Comment: @Lasse, I can post my source code yes. It includes debugging info commented out, you can uncomment it to see the full paths.

Comment: @Rosarch, if you want suggestions for optimizations we first need to know what the correct solution is and how it is calculated. None of us know how to get the numbers you have. If I'm calculating paths incorrectly you need to tell us more information about how we should be doing it. It might be a good idea to compare the paths our solutions give for n=4 and see what paths my solution generates that yours doesn't and decide which of us is wrong. You can run my code to see the paths my program has considered, but you need to do be able to the same for your program so we can compare results.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be at least as difficult as [enumerating polyominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Enumeration_of_polyominoes). There are no known fast algorithms for doing this, and the best known algorithms struggle after n=50. I doubt there is a fast way to solve this problem.

I'm not even going to pretend that this is an optimal solution but it might be useful as a reference solution. I think it at least gives the correct answer, although it takes some time. It solves the problem recursively by finding all paths of length n-1, then checking for all possible places it can add one more tile and removing duplicate solutions. It has a particularly ugly part where it checks for duplicate by converting the path to a string and comparing the strings, but it was fast to write.

Here's the output it generates:

```
n = 1, number of paths found = 1
n = 2, number of paths found = 4
n = 3, number of paths found = 22
n = 4, number of paths found = 113
n = 5, number of paths found = 571
n = 6, number of paths found = 2816
n = 7, number of paths found = 13616
n = 8, number of paths found = 64678
n = 9, number of paths found = 302574
```

And here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public struct Tile
{
    public Tile(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }
    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;
    public IEnumerable<Tile> GetNeighbours(int gridSize)
    {
        if (X > 0)
            yield return new Tile(X - 1, Y);
        if (X < gridSize - 1)
            yield return new Tile(X + 1, Y);
        if (Y > 0)
            yield return new Tile(X, Y - 1);
        if (Y < gridSize - 1)
            yield return new Tile(X, Y + 1);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0},{1})", X, Y);
    }
}

public class Path
{
    public Path(Tile[] tiles) { Tiles = tiles; }
    public Tile[] Tiles { get; private set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join("", Tiles.Select(tile => tile.ToString()).ToArray());
    }
}

public class PathFinder
{
    public IEnumerable<Path> FindPaths(int n, int gridSize)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; ++x)
                for (int y = 0; y < gridSize; ++y)
                    yield return new Path(new Tile[] { new Tile(x, y) });
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> pathsSeen = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (Path shortPath in FindPaths(n - 1, gridSize))
            {
                foreach (Tile tile in shortPath.Tiles)
                {
                    foreach (Tile neighbour in tile.GetNeighbours(gridSize))
                    {
                        // Ignore tiles that are already included in the path.
                        if (shortPath.Tiles.Contains(neighbour))
                            continue;

                        Path newPath = new Path(shortPath.Tiles
                            .Concat(new Tile[] { neighbour })
                            .OrderBy(t => t.X)
                            .ThenBy(t => t.Y)
                            .ToArray());

                        string pathKey = newPath.ToString();
                        if (!pathsSeen.ContainsKey(pathKey))
                        {
                            pathsSeen[pathKey] = null;
                            yield return newPath;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        PathFinder pathFinder = new PathFinder();
        for (int n = 1; n <= 9; ++n)
        {
            List<Path> paths = pathFinder.FindPaths(n, n).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("n = {0}, number of paths found = {1}", n, paths.Count);
            //foreach (Path path in paths)
            //    Console.WriteLine(path.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would using a n-bit integer, like a 64-bit integer, speed up looking for path duplicates? Consider each tile a bit in the integer, which would at least allow you to use a basic integer to generate a key for the dictionary. For smaller n's, you could also use the integer directly into a boolean-array to figure out if you've seen it before. Just a thought.

Comment: It seems like that would help for small n where it runs fast anyway, but not for large n where the actual problem is. I'm considering splitting the alg. into two: first part would identify what shapes are possible without placing them, and the second part would calculate in how many different ways the shape can be placed onto the grid. The second half is actually just a simple multiplication based on the size of the bounding box of the shape. But since we can't even agree what the correct answer is or even what a "path" is, I don't want to make any optimizations just yet. Correctness first.

Comment: I think the first part of the two-part optimized algorithm I suggested above is equivalent to enumerating polyominos: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Enumeration_of_polyominoes.